# Blurred modal UITableViewController transparent only during transition?

Tags: ios9, uimodaltransitionstyle, visual-effects

In iOS9 I am presenting a UITableViewController modally over current context and at viewWillAppear I am blurring it like this:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:effectStyle];
UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];

[blurEffectView setFrame:self.tableView.bounds];

self.tableView.backgroundView = blurEffectView;
self.tableView.separatorEffect = [UIVibrancyEffect effectForBlurEffect:blurEffect];
```

The blur is working fine but transparency is showing the caller UIViewController view underneath it only as long as it is transitioning. As soon as the transition completes the underneath view is no longer visible.

Am I missing something? I thought that specifying modal transition style overCurrentContext was working fine to achieve this?

This is the effect during transition, see the red circle underneath?

[image]

This is when transition has ended, the red circle is gone, do not pay attention to the grey numbers in front, those actually belong to the presented view controller.

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?